# Как сделать загрузчик фото в форме html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

http://www.scrabber.net/K8AQM
Как это реализовать?
Чтобы можно было и загружать фото и удалять (поворачивать не обязательно, но если подскажите, будет мне на пользу) ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам понадобится webAPI, принимающий картинку и возвращающий ссылку на картинку, затем:

html:

```
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file"">
   <img src=""/>
```

js:

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', upload);

function upload(event){
 var data = new FormData();
 $.each(event.target.files, function(key, value) {
  data.append(key, value);
 });

 $.ajax({
  url: 'vebapiURL',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(success)
  {
    $('img').attr('src', success.uploadedIMGURL);
  }
 });
}
```

Выбираете файл, отправляете его аяксом на сервер, получаете ссылку на него от сервера, обновляете картинку в dom. Дальше с ней можно проделывать какие-нибудь манипуляции, например добавить в канвас, а там уже вертеть, сайзить и скейлить.

Answer (score 0):

В теории: 
Сначала файл отправляем на сервер

```
 <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <p><input type="file" name="pic"></p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="отправить"></p>
  </form>
```

Потом по клику на кнопку "удалить" отправляем запрос на сервер и там удаляем и в ответ присылаем новый список к примеру =)